# Deploy two apps to heroku and connected by RESTFul web services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm having 2 rails applications, and I want to deploy both on Heroku. For example, app1 will be the app for desktop and app2 will be only for mobile devices (I'll be using jQuery Mobile). App2 will get data from app1 by RESTFul web services.

How should I do that in Heroku? App1 will be the main one (http://www.mycompany.com), app2 will be deployed to (http://m.mycompany.com)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a web service, or how to deploy them on Heroku? There's nothing special about the Heroku environment that would change how you build your service, you just point app2's ActiveResource model at app1's domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to do this. What you need to do is follow something like this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 . Essentially, once you get subdomains setup inside your rails app then you can use your views to dictate what happens with the m.domain.com and that is still plugged into your DB.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, so I don't have to have 2 apps running in heroku right?

Comment: @toy No, you don't have to and you probably don't want to. You just need to setup subdomains and then route to your views correctly.